# Putting bitmap on MediaSessionCompat not showing ART WORK in lockscreen ?

Tags: android, bitmap, lockscreen, mediametadataretriever, android-mediasession

```
mediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, trackDataNowPlaying.JukeBoxCategoryName)
                            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, trackDataNowPlaying.TrackName)
                            .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, Math.round(trackDataNowPlaying.Length))
                            .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, resource)
                            .build());
```

Putting bitmap on MediaSessionCompat not showing ART WORK in lockscreen. Above code used when on track changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the way to achieve that is through setting the Large Icon when building your notification with `setLargeIcon`

You can also use the `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` and define the player icons and actions you desire for the user to interact with there.
Apply this style to the notification with `setStyle`

Comment: bro used the all things you mentioned above but it is not work for me check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742921/why-mediasession-not-changing-the-lock-screen-background-may-be-bitmap-size-pro